# Reading every line in a CSV and using it to query an API

Tags: ruby, csv

I have the following Ruby code:

```
require 'octokit.rb'
require 'csv.rb'

CSV.foreach("actors.csv") do |row|
  CSV.open("node_attributes.csv", "wb") do |csv|
    csv << [Octokit.user "userid"]
  end
end
```

- I have a csv called `actors.csv` where every row has one entry - a string with a userid.
- I want to go through all the rows, and for each row do `Octokit.user "userid"`, and then store the output from each query on a separate row in a CSV - `node_attributes.csv`.

My code does not seem to do this? How can I modify it to make this work?

Comment: Can someone who voted to close help me to understand why? I'm happy to improve the question, if guidance can be given.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
require 'csv'
DOC = 'actors.csv'
DOD = 'new_output.csv'
holder = CSV.read(DOC)
```

You can navigate it by calling

```
holder[0][0]
=> data in the array 
holder[1][0] 
=> moar data in array
```

make sense?

```
#make this a loop
profile = []
profile[0] = holder[0][0]
profile[1] = holder[1][0]
profile[2] = 'whatever it is you want to store in the new cell'

CSV.open(DOD, "a") do |data|
data << profile.map
end

#end the loop here
```

That last bit of code will print whatever you want into a new csv file